# SQL - If statement seemingly ignoring 'AND'

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I made the following stored procedure which will be called when creating a new employee.
The insert should be successful so long as the employee doesnt already exist in the Employee table.

To check for this I decided to check FirstName, LastName and DateOfBirth. If a row contains a 3 way match of all those columns, the insert should fail.

What i'm seeing is that the If statement is treating my AND as an OR.
If one match occurs the insert fails.

After some searching around I cant see to see what is wrong with my If structure.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
            Create Procedure CreateEmployee
            (
            @Role_ID Int,
            @FirstName Varchar(50),
            @LastName Varchar(50),
            @DateOfBirth Varchar(50),
            @Active Bit
            )
            As
            Begin

            If Not Exists (Select FirstName From Employee Where FirstName = @FirstName)
                AND Not Exists (Select LastName From Employee Where LastName = @LastName)
                AND Not Exists (Select DateOfBirth From Employee Where DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth)

                Begin
                Insert Into Employee (Role_ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Active)
                Values (@Role_ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @Active)
                End

            Else
                Begin
                Select 'User already exists!'
                End

            End
```

Comment: @bonCodigo: why did you add mysql tag? I can't see any reference to mysql in the question. is this mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 6):

Why are you not just running 1 query for your check?

```
If Not Exists (Select 1 From Employee 
               Where FirstName = @FirstName 
                     and LastName = @LastName 
                     and DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth)
    begin
        ...
```

Comment: Hmmm. That's ... much better : /

Thanks alot!

Comment: @Corgalas No problems. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way *(`@@rowcount` for sql server)*: using `Where not exists`. [Similar Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70617/21)

```
Insert Into Employee (Role_ID, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth, Active)
Select @Role_ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @DateOfBirth, @Active
Where not exists (
  select 1 from Employee where FirstName = @FirstName 
                         and LastName = @LastName 
                         and DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth
)

If @@rowcount=0 select 'User already exists!'
```